# why my index page does not load in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I started a django project and the index template doesn't work it just load  django's main page
in fact I have opened the tutorial and copied word for word and it still doesn't work

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'students/index.html')
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'students',
]
```

my main urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('students.urls')),
]
```

urls.py file for my app called students

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),


]
```

my index.html file(I tried putting the body outside the head tag but it also didn't work so i copied  what was done in the tutorial

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Student management </title>

   <body>
     <h1>Hello world!</h1>
   </body>
 </head>

</html>
```

Comment: according to html structure, you cannot add body tag inside head tag

Comment: please provide settings.py file

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I edit the html body tag outside of head still doesn't work, I already provided settings.py

Comment: Only shared installed apps from settings file. please provide whole settings file

Comment: You need to restart the server in another port using `python manage.py runserver 5000` then see what happens and yes body tag must be outisde the head tag.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Student Management</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello world</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>`. Try this template.

Comment: @SunderamDubey still didn't work

Comment: @SunderamDubey  thanks, i just solve it  i discovered that my app was named Student in capital  in apps.py and i needed to close all files before i run server looks like my typing doesn't save automatically

Comment: @Micolashhostofthenightmare Anyway, answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

ok so I just solve it i discovered that my app was named Student in capital in apps.py and i needed to close all files before i run server looks like my typing doesn't save automatically